# Convergence by writing an expansion first

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, mathematical-physics

How to determine if $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n  \frac{1}{n^2 +3n +2}$$ converges or not?

I expand first the series as shown below to observe if I can rewrite it to another simpler form of series but I could not find any way.
$$ \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12} -\frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{30} -\frac{1}{42}$$

Or is there any faster test for convergence without the need of expanding the series?

Comment: We can take $x\in[0;1]$ and consider $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n  \frac{1}{n^2 +3n +2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n  \Bigl(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\Bigr)=$$-\frac{1}{x}(-x+x^2/2-x^3/3+-...)-\frac{1}{x^2}(x^2/2-x^3/3+-...)=\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}(x-\log(1+x))$. Then $S=f(1)=2\log2-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely convergent because $|\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n^{2}+3n+3}| \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^{2}} <\infty$. Note that the term corresponding to $n=0$ can be ignored for determining convergence.

Comment: yes, it is.. but what if we only find for the convergence without the absolute value?

Comment: @JordanG Any absolutely convergent series is convergent.